# Strange bug with sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I'm facing BIG and strange problem , i have sqlite android database app on many mobile phones what is works perfectly , but when uses my app on lenovo or asus 7 inch tablet I'm facing no records stored in database , so i think maybe there some problems with getting current data with local.getdefualt()

here is my code :

INSERT statment :

```
public long addCheckPoint(String fleetNumber, String NoOFStudents,String Location_Longitude,String Location_Latitude){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String ActionDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("FleetNumber", fleetNumber); 
        values.put("CheckPointID", CheckPoint(fleetNumber)); 
        values.put("NoOFStudents", NoOFStudents);
        values.put("Location_Longitude", Location_Longitude);
        values.put("Location_Latitude", Location_Latitude);
        values.put("ActionDate", ActionDate);
        values.put("PathStatus", "Open");

        return  db.insert("CheckPoints",null, values);
    }
```

getting result statment :

```
    public Cursor getCheckPointRows(String fleetNumber){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String ActionDate =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    String qq = "select CheckPointID , FleetNumber, NoOFStudents , ActionDate from CheckPoints where FleetNumber = "+ fleetNumber +" and date(ActionDate)='"+ActionDate+"'" ;
    Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery(qq, null);

      if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
          return cursor;
}

     db.close();
    return cursor;

}
```

table strc

```
          // SQL statement to create CheckPoints table
    String CREATE_CheckPoints_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE CheckPoints ( " +
            "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +
            "FleetNumber INTEGER, "+
            "CheckPointID INTEGER,"+
            "NoOFStudents INTEGER,"+
            "Location_Longitude TEXT,"+
            "Location_Latitude TEXT,"+
            "PathStatus TEXT,"+
            "ActionDate TEXT)" ;
```

Comment: Device specific bugs are hard to trouble shoot.. but I would consider checking out Joda Time for any date functions: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: From your cod, When you are going to store the date into database, you are going to format it with "yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss" and when retrieving this value as a date there will be a problem for sure because you will be converting it into a date

Comment: Why do you believe that the problem is with `Locale.getDefault()`?